Enum within RestEasy @RestForm?
I have a JAX-RS service that handles multipart PUT operations, with a request object mapped using the @RestForm annotation.  All of the parameters within the @RestForm are serialized/deserialized properly, and I'm able to see them come across to my JAX-RS endpoint method.  However, when I added a property to the form that is an Enum it does not seem to be mapped correctly.  When I PUT a request with this Enum value set, my JAX-RS endpoint sees the value as null.
My form is quite simple and looks something like this:
public class MyEnumForm {

@RestForm("paramA")
private String paramA = null;

@RestForm("paramB")
private String paramB = null;

@RestForm("enumParam")
private MyEnumType enumParam = null;

...snip...

}

My JAX-RS endpoint method looks like this...
@Path("/myendpoint")
@PUT
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response testPut(@MultipartForm MyEnumForm) {

...snip...

}

Am I missing an annotation on the enum in my form class?  Is there something special I have to do for enum types in this scenario?

What version of RESTEasy are you using?

I'm using RestEasy bundled as part of Quarkus 3.10.  It looks like RestEasy 6.2.7.

Have you tried @ BeanParam instead of @MultipartForm ?

I'm using @ MultipartForm because there are file uploads as part of the PUT request.  I've tried changing the @ MultipartForm annotation to @ BeanParam, but the result is the same.  I changed the @ RestForm annotation on the Enum filed to @ FormParam, but again the same results.

@Shadowman, you can also include your files in MyEnumForm with @ RestForm(ALL) List

@Serkan yes, that is how I'm handling the file uploads.  I just did not show that as part of my code example, as the issue is localized to the problem with the enum.

@Shadowman, just map your enum as a string then. And make a helper method in your enum to convert from string to enum.

@Serkan I can certainly do that.  I was just hoping that there was a way to get Resteasy to do the mapping like it does with other fields.

The issue was that my enum needed a public static fromString(String) method to convert the provided String value to an Enum instance.  Once that was added, RestEasy converted it properly.
